# AJAX search as you type?

Tags: plugins, search, ajax

I'm trying to implement a kind of "search as you type" feature with the Search bar.  Essentially, I'd like to have the user begin to type, make some kind of ajax request after each key, and then populate a div with "Related searches" as they type.  Any good plugins for this or should I bake it up from scratch?

Comment: I like your question, as I would like something similar, however, the mods will probably be around to shut this thread down, as WPAnswers no longer allows plugin suggestion questions... UNFORTUNATELY

Comment: Well it doesn't necessarily have to be a plugin.  It could just AJAX to the built-in search page, get some JSON back and parse it.  I just don't know how to make this efficient enough that it won't bomb my server.

Comment: Something like this? *How to create live autofill search?* - http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/42891/12615

Comment: @brasofilo perfect, I was able to edit that for my exact needs.  Did a search but didn't stumble upon that.

Comment: Glad it worked. Would be nice if you published your solution as an Answer, so this Q don't hang in the unanswered list :)

Answer (score 0):

I have developed an ajax search plugin a few weeks ago. There is a free version available at the wordpress plugin repository. Feel free to explore the source code :)

You can find it here: [Ajax Search Lite](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ajax-search-lite/)

There is also a commercial version, maybe you are interested: [Ajax Search Pro](http://codecanyon.net/item/ajax-search-pro-for-wordpress/3357410?sso&ref=anago)

You can check out the demos and see if it fits your need. Also, I provide quick and free support if something goes wrong.
Im not sure if this is what you are looking for, but I hope I could help.